# error in OnLongClickListener() method

Tags: android

```
akashButton.setOnLongClickListener(
    new Button.OnLongClickListener(){

         public boolean onClick(View v){

              TextView akashHacked = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.akashHacked);
              akashHacked.setText("Wow, that was a long one");
              return true;
         }
    }
);
```

On writing this code in android studio I am getting a red line under `Button.OnLongClickListener()` and the error says

> " class'Anonymous class derived from OnLongClickListener' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'OnLongClick(View)' in 'OnLongClickListener' "`

Please help me in fixing this error.

Comment: The error is telling you what is wrong and how to fix it. Which part do you not understand?

Comment: how to fix it!..I am new to android development and don't really have much idea yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you will have to retrieve your button from your layout :

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButtonId);
```

then, you will have to set your button's listener :

```
myButton.setOnLongClickListener(new Button.OnLongClickListener(){
      public boolean onLongClick(View v){
          // do whatever you want here
      }
 });
```

Comment: This is exactly how I did it..I had already retrieved my button from the layout I just didnt show it here in the question.
But my syntax is exactly like you have shown.
It's still not working :(

Comment: oh ok Sorry, I see your mistake, please see the updated answer (onLongClick)

Comment: Cool ! don't forget to mark the question as answered ;)

Comment: on the left of my answer, you can see a little check mark, click on it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented `OnItemClickListener` (or `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`)? If so, remove it.